# Matching new lines

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regexp:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"HESAID:|SHESAID:")
```

It's working correctly. I use it to split by multiple delimiters like this:

```
result = pattern.split(content)
```

What I want to add is verification so that the split does NOT happend unless HESAID: or SHESAID: are placed on new lines. This is not working:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\nHESAID:\n|\nSHESAID:\n")
```

Please help.

Comment: You need to use multiline regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful if you elaborated on how exactly it is not working, but I am guessing that the issue is that it does not match consecutive lines of HESAID/SHESAID.  You can fix this by using beginning and end of line anchors instead of actually putting `\n` in your regex:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^HESAID:$|^SHESAID:$', re.MULTILINE)
```

The `re.MULTILINE` flag is necessary so that `^` and `$` match at beginning and end of lines, instead of just the beginning and end of the string.

I would probably rewrite the regex as follows, the `?` after the `S` makes it optional:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^S?HESAID:$', re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: @Droogans Yep! The hat looked ugly on the auto-generated box.